# Joining two different datasets using multiple keyvalues

Tags: python, sql, linux, join, multikey

I have two sets of data.

The first dataset looks like:

```
Storm_ID,Cell_ID,Wind_speed
2,10236258,27
2,10236300,58
2,10236301,25
3,10240400,51
```

The second dataset looks like:

```
Storm_ID,Cell_ID,Storm_surge
2,10236299,0.27
2,10236300,0.27
2,10236301,0.35
2,10240400,0.35
2,10240401,0.81
4,10240402,0.11
```

Now I want an output which looks something like this:

```
Storm_ID,Cell_ID,Wind_speed,Storm_surge
2,10236258,27,0
2,10236299,0,0.27
2,10236300,58,0.27
2,10236301,25,0.35
2,10240400,0,0.35
2,10240401,0,0.81
3,10240400,51,0
4,10240402,0,0.11
```

I tried join command in Linux to perform this task and failed badly. Join command skipped the rows which didn't match in  the database. I can use Matlab but the size of the data is more than 100 GB which is making it very difficult for this task. 
Can someone please guide me on this one please. Can I use SQL or python to complete this task. I appreciate your help Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Gordon The small set of database has been represented in the above example. Sorry, if this is not the right way to do it. I am new to stack overflow

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure if he wants to use a database at all. It looks like he has a CSV file and wants to use the UNIX `join` command https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/ To me it looks like an interesting question, but he still needs to explain a bit more what he means with `skipped the rows which didn't match in the database`. As if he has the data in SQL and in CSV, and when he compares a SQL JOIN to the CSV UNIX join, the results differ. We can't know why from the info given.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `full outer join`:

```
select storm_id, cell_id,
       coalesce(d1.wind_speed, 0) as wind_speed,
       coalesce(d2.storm_surge, 0) as storm_surge
from dataset1 d1 full join
     dataset2 d2
     using (storm_id, cell_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shell-Only Solution**

**Make a backup of your files first**

Assuming your files are called wind1.txt and wind2.txt

You could apply these sets of shell commands:

```
perl -pi -E "s/,/_/" wind*
perl -pi -E 's/(.$)/$1,0/' wind1.txt
perl -pi -E "s/,/,0,/"     wind2.txt
join --header -a 1 -a 2 wind1.txt wind2.txt > outfile.txt
```

Intermediate Result

```
Storm_ID_Cell_ID,Wind_speed,0
2_10236258,27,0
2_10236299,0,0.27
2_10236300,0,0.27
2_10236300,58,0
2_10236301,0,0.35
2_10236301,25,0
2_10240400,0,0.35
2_10240401,0,0.81
3_10240400,51,0
4_10240402,0,0.11
```

Now rename in line 0 to "storm_surge", replace first _ with "," in digits

```
perl -pi -E "s/Wind_speed,0/Wind_speed,Storm_surge/" outfile.txt
perl -pi -E 's/^(\d+)_/$1,/' outfile.txt
perl -pi -E "s/Storm_ID_Cell_ID/Storm_ID,Cell_ID/" outfile.txt
```

Intermediate result:

```
Storm_ID,Cell_ID,Wind_speed,Storm_surge
2,10236258,27,0
2,10236299,0,0.27
2,10236300,0,0.27
2,10236300,58,0
2,10236301,0,0.35
2,10236301,25,0
2,10240400,0,0.35
2,10240401,0,0.81
3,10240400,51,0
4,10240402,0,0.11
```

Finally run  this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","}{arr[$1,$2]+=$3+$4 }END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' outfile.txt  | sort
```

(Sorry - Q was closed while answering)

Answer (score 0):

awk -F, -v OFS=, '{x = $1 "," $2} FNR == NR {a[x] = $3; b[x] = 0; next} {b[x] = $3} !a[x] {a[x] = 0} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i]}' f1 f2 | sort -n

Since it's a loop, awk produces random order. Hence sorting at the end.